# Import Error: no module named cloud.ml

Tags: python, tensorflow, gcloud, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to follow the instructions to use local predictions in tensorflow as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/local/predict).  Running the command `gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=~/PycharmProjects/nlc/export/1/ --json-instances=test.json` gives me the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.local.predict) Cannot import google.cloud.ml. Please verify "python -c 'import google.cloud.ml'" works. Please verify the installed cloudml sdk version with: "python -c 'import google.cloud.ml as cloudml; print cloudml.__version__'".
```

What do I need to install in order to get the `google.cloud.ml` package?  All it says on that link is

> It requires the TensorFlow SDK be installed locally

Tensorflow is working properly on my system and `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` outputs `1.0.1`.  I have also made sure to install the python utilities by running `pip install -U google-api-python-client`.  What else do I need to install?

This is being attempted on a VM running Ubuntu, so that handles the requirement:

> Only Debian based systems are supported at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug with gcloud that will be fixed in tomorrow's (2017/03/15) release. Sometime tomorrow, please run

```
gcloud components update
```

Apologies for the inconvenience.