# cloud ml predict FAILED_PRECONDITION and value for field [projectsId]

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

The predict command I have been using for quite some time began encountering an error this weekend:

```
$ gcloud beta ml predict --model my_model --json-instances my_instance.json

WARNING: The `gcloud beta ml` commands have been renamed and will soon be removed. Please use `gcloud ml-engine` instead.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml.predict) value for field [projectsId] for in collection [ml.projects.models] is required but was not provided
```

I do not understand how to fix the error.

To investigate whether the error is associated with the soon to be removed 'cloud beta ml' command, I replaced it with 'gcloud ml-engine' but encountered this error:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine predict --model my_model --json-instances my_instance.json
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.predict) HTTP request failed. Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Precondition check failed.",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
```

I do not understand how to fix this second error.  Presumably, its root cause is the same as the first error.

How can I get more detail about fixing this error(s)?

Note: this question appears similar this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765968/google-cloud-ml-failed-precondition) asked by @jbird, but is not the same.

Comment: I'm actually having the same problem, despite the fact that prediction is working just fine when using `gcloud ml-engine local predict` with the exact same model and instance data. No luck with a solution thus far.

Comment: @kbhomes do you also get the same error as me ("...value for field [projectsId] for in collection...") for 'gcloud beta ml predict'?

Comment: Yep, I get that error as well (although I just started working with ML Engine today so I wasn't previously using `gcloud beta ml predict` before)

Comment: I have the same problem. Predictions were working a couple weeks ago. Something broke in an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gcloud tool has been updated so that the `ml-engine` set of commands is the officially supported way to interact with the service. The `gcloud beta ml` codepath is out-of-date. The following should work:

```
gcloud beta ml-engine predict --model my_model --json-instances my_instance.json
```

(Note the presence of the keyword `beta`).

The reason for the 400 error when using `gcloud ml-engine predict` (note the absence of the keyword `beta`) is because your model is not a [SavedModel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md). In that set of commands (non-beta), we only support SavedModel.

You can continue to use your existing models via the old endpoint (`gcloud beta ...`), but we expect to deprecate that functionality soon, so we recommend exporting new models as SavedModels and deploying them via `gcloud ml-engine`.

Comment: marking this as answered, thank you!  When you "recommend exporting new models as SavedModels", what does that mean for my existing models, please?  (My existing models were trained using https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow.)  Is there a way for one to convert an existing model vs one has to train an entirely new model?

Comment: @rhaertel80 I'm confused by this, since like @ChuckFinley I used the training method that he linked, running the code pretty much exactly and obtaining a `saved_model.pb` file and `variables` folder and in fact the code uses a `SavedModelBuilder` to export the model. Is this not a `SavedModel` compatible with ML Engine? Additionally, `gcloud ml-engine local predict` works perfectly fine with the exact same model on my machine.

Comment: @kbhomes what command did you use to deploy the model and what are you using for prediction (paying close attention to `beta` vs. not and `ml` vs. `ml-engine`).

Comment: @rhaertel80 the commands are 'gcloud beta ml models create "$MODEL_NAME"' and 'gcloud beta ml versions create "$VERSION_NAME" \
  --model "$MODEL_NAME" \
  --origin "${GCS_PATH}/training/model"'

Comment: @ChuckFinley. Thanks, I'm guessing predict call uses `gcloud beta ml predict`?

Comment: @ChuckFinley I just added a post describing how you can convert the model. Warning: it's untested code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968628/how-do-i-convert-a-cloudml-alpha-model-to-a-savedmodel/42968629#42968629

Comment: @rhaertel80 you correctly guessed the predict call.  Thank you for the additional post!  I will gratefully review and use it.